# Why do I keep getting UnauthorizedAccessException in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions

I am an admin on the machine and I am trying to delete a folder. This folder contains a application that is calling out to a uninstalled service. I don't need it, therefore I don't want it. When ever I try to run remove-item all I get is Permission Denied, UnauthorizedAccessException. Am I missing something? Did I do something wrong?

Exact command:

```
Remove-Item -Path "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\Muse.MuseHub_1.0.1.693_x64__rb9pth70m6nz6"
```

Intended result: deleted folder

Answer (score 0):

By design (at least by Microsoft's design) you can't natively/directly delete content from the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ folder, which is where all the MS Store apps live.

That is regardless of whether you're running as admin, are logged in directly as an admin, doing it via cmd.exe or powershell etc.

Note, **DO NOT CHANGE THE PERMISSIONS** on that folder. Doing so will likely break various things in Windows in weird and interesting ways.

A work around to the issue was mentioned here https://superuser.com/questions/1495993/how-can-i-free-up-space-taken-up-by-an-incomplete-microsoft-store-download a while ago, though you should only use it if you're certain you want to delete that folder.

Download and install 7zip on your machine (the same trick works with some other apps, but not all, and 7zip is one I know it does work with), then start the application elevated as admin. Navigate to that folder, and you'll find you're able to delete the folder from within that interface.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you shouldn't try  to modify the content of `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` directly; it is managed by the [AppX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/appx-portal) infrastructure, as used by Microsoft Store.

Instead, try to remove the application (package) via the [`Remove-AppXPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage) cmdlet:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator
Remove-AppXPackage -WhatIf -AllUsers -Package Muse.MuseHub_1.0.1.693_x64__rb9pth70m6nz6
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>